# Python Pandas: How to sort group bar chart?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code that is currently displaying the group bar chart.

```
pd.crosstab(train_data['workclass'],train_data['income']).plot(kind="bar")
plt.xlabel('Workclass')
plt.ylabel('Income Count')
plt.suptitle("Training Data: Workclass vs Income", fontweight="bold")
```

My data looks like this:

[image]

The current chart looks like this:

[image]

I want to display the chart by sorting the orange section (income `>50K`) in descending order. So the tallest orange bar should be on the left side. How do I do that?

**Update**
I tried the following codes and get the following error.

```
CT = pd.crosstab(train_data['education'],train_data['income'])
CT.sort_values(train_data['income'], ascending=False).plot(kind='bar')
plt.xlabel('Education')
plt.ylabel('Income Count')
plt.suptitle("Training Data: Education vs Income", fontweight="bold")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Try the following code:

```
pd.crosstab(train_data['education'],train_data['income'].sort_values('income', ascending=False)).plot(kind-'bar')
plt.xlabel('Workclass')
plt.ylabel('Income Count')
plt.suptitle("Training Data: Workclass vs Income", fontweight="bold")
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't think I show you what the data table looks like. I updated my question now.

Comment: Could you show code where you are doing the count of the people with income >50. You need to apply the ```sort_values ``` where you are doing the count of people of each group where the income is > 50k

Comment: `pd.crosstab(train_data['education'],train_data['income']).plot(kind="bar")` The part that apply `train_data["income"]` does it.

Comment: Hi, I tried your recommendation by twisting the code a little bit. I got some errors.

Comment: What accounts for your income count?

Comment: I believe by applying `pd.crosstab`, this automatically account for the income count